# Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified in my .NET Core 2.1 Project --

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, sdk, asp.net-core-2.1

I am getting the following error in my .Net Core 2.1 Project.

```
Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified. The most likely cause is an older incompatible version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor, 
or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web used by this project. Please target a newer version of the .NET Core SDK.
```

Clciking on the rror shows the following portion in the codegeneration.targets file

```
<Target Name="_EnsureRazorTasksAssemblyDefined">
    <Error 
      Text="Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified. The most likely cause is an older incompatible version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor, or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web used by this project. Please target a newer version of the .NET Core SDK." 
      Condition="'$(RazorSdkBuildTasksAssembly)' == ''" />
  </Target>
```

As a remedy, I tried to update all relevant packages in my project. Even the update does not happen!
Cleaned unloaded and then reloaded the solution. Built it, but the same error is appearing. Exactly what is it indicating towards? I also downloaded and installed the framework 2.2 for Core let me tell you that.
But no nothing seems to solve this.

What's the problem?

*** Update
after running the command line for listing the sdks I found this->

```
1.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.1.300-preview1-008174 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
3.0.100-preview3-010431 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

So what now?

Comment: How did you create .net core 2.1 project? Run `dotnet --list-sdks` and share us the result in commandline.

Comment: Hi @TaoZhou I got the following --

1.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.300-preview1-008174 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview3-010431 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

what next,

Comment: How did you create .net core 2.1 project?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2017 -
create new project - core - .net core(2.1) - Asp.Net Core Web Application - API Type and Framework 2.1 Core                 that's how @TaoZhou